# set selection range after set innerText (angular js)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, selection, contenteditable

I have two directives. The first one called `restricted-text` watch for ngModel changes and replace current value with old one if new one doesn't respect given regexp. It works very well when placed on input.

The second one is a directive called `input-editable`. It's a span[contendeditable]. It works very well too.

Then, we plug the first one on the second :

```
<input-editable ng-model="lol" restricted-text="^[a-z]+$"></input-editable>
```

and it fails…
When I type a not allowed character, then, the content of the spec is well changed. But ! The crret go back to the start of the span. I would like the caret stays at the same place, or at worst, go the the end like an input. I've tried lot of things with getSelection and createRange, all that I get is the caret position. The cursor don't move when I call setStart.

Have a look [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CfAo5ZgxvMohwdIgNg12)

Comment: just a question what is prout, I cant find it in your code, how is that possible?

Comment: "prout" is the text I want to attach to my editable span. It's located in the directive's template.

Comment: Thanks, I dont know why I didnt check there :)